# ktor dynamic keys serialization and json preprosesing

Tags: json-deserialization, ktor

Is there anyway in Ktor to alter a json before deserialization process? In the example below there is a json with dynamic keys in which i need to remove the "token" key as it is of a string type instead of an object type as the other keys.
When i urn the code i get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.JsonDecodingException: Expected class kotlinx.serialization.json.JsonObject as the serialized body of shell.remoting.Market, but had class kotlinx.serialization.json.JsonLiteral
```

I'm not sure if there is another better way to do it. Any suggestion will be appreciated, thanks

```
object MarketMapSerializer :
    JsonTransformingSerializer<Map<String, Market>>(MapSerializer(String.serializer(), Market.serializer())) {
    override fun transformSerialize(element: JsonElement): JsonElement =
        JsonObject(element.jsonObject.filterNot { (k, _) ->
            k == "token"
        })
}

@Serializable
data class Market(
    val stations: List<Station>,
)

@Serializable
data class Station(
    @JsonNames("iata_code")
    val iataCode: String,
    val destinations: List<String>,
)


fun main() {
    val jsonString = """
        {
            "Republica Dominicana": {
                "stations": [
                    {
                        "iata_code": "PUJ",
                        "destinations": [
                            "ADZ",
                            "BAQ",
                            "VVC"
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            "Brasil": {
                "stations": [
                    {
                        "iata_code": "AJO",
                        "destinations": [
                            "ADZ",
                            "BAQ",
                            "VVC"
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJkb3RSRVogQVBJIiwianRpIjoiYTVhZDM4NmYtOGViNy0yOWQ5LWZkMGYtM2Q3MzQwZmRhOGI2IiwiaXNzIjoiZG90UkVaIEFQSSJ9.V2YfXCt9r7Tzae9SYSoj-qIyxjRc9YoE2XPoIQQNI9U"
        }
    """.trimIndent()
    println(
        Json.decodeFromString(
            MarketMapSerializer,
            jsonString
        )
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace `transformSerialize` with the `transformDeserialize` since you're doing deserialization.